# How to identify a db transaction and use it on both sides of a RPC

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, postgresql, transactions

In our system we use transactions heavily. Our platform will automatically roll back the transaction at the very end of a request if any error messages were found in a known message collection.  Because the system is very large we still have to call in to legacy code from time to time. The legacy code runs on a different server and is called synchronously via RPC.

Unfortunately, a separate transaction is created by the legacy code, which forces us to explicitly commit any changes that the legacy code relies on before calling the legacy code and also the legacy code can commit its changes if everything goes smoothly.

The platform doesn't provide any nice way to identify this and to clean up the data.  This causes a bunch of nasty cases where something went wrong either in the new code or the legacy code and data has been created committed and orphaned.

I am wondering if there is a mechanism to identify a transaction by Id or something like that, and pick it up and use it in the legacy code. Both the new codebase and the legacy codebase talk directly (2-tier) to the database server, and there is always a single database server.  We don't have any concept of distributed databases.

Edit: TLDR; I am wondering if there is a non DBMS specific way to identify a database transaction and to use it.  If there is only DBMS ways to do it do any oracle / sql-server / postgres gurus know how?

Comment: By "transaction", do you mean SQL Server transactions, as created by `begin transaction`?

Comment: @Blorgbeard yeah although not necessarily sql server. we support sql server / oracle and postgres

Comment: Ok. Well, the answer will be RDBMS specific. Looks like you might be able to swing it with [a deprecated method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174403.aspx) for sql server.

Comment: Thanks @Blorgbeard. I don't think that will work for me in this case (especially since its deprecated) and I can't see how to do the same with the superseding MARS.